# Errors in updating Markupsafe

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

I am a very new python user. I am interested working with anaconda and Jupiter notebook for metabolic engineering experiments. However, I cannot use my Jupiter notebook anymore due to the errors n markup safe. Someone suggested me to update it through terminal, because I always failed when I updating it through anaconda. However, I always failed to do verifying transaction after downloaded the files (attached). Could you please suggest a way to solve this problem? I would really appreciate for all your support.
Best regards,
Deper
[Error after downloading packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGw88.png)

getting suggestions to solve my problems